# FullCalendar and Event DateTIme format in different browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datetime, firefox

So, in my site, I'm using full calendar for its intended purpose. Through a JSON call to a WebService, in my aspx code, I'm getting all the events for a given month from the database. Those are then fed to the calendar. That works quite nicely under Chrome, and the events display properly; unfortunately, under Firefox, (and others) I'm not so successful. If I display event using the most simple form possible, it works in FireFox just fine:

```
events: [
        {

            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2016-05-01',
            description: 'This is a cool event'
        },

        {

            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2016-05-02',
            description: 'This is a cool event'
        }
    ]
```

But if I use the code, I have to get the Events dynamically from the database and display them, and then it all fails (again it works on Chrome just fine):

```
 events: $.map(data.d,function (item, i) 
                   { 
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.start = formatDate(item.StartDate);
                        event.end = formatDate(item.EndDate);
                        event.title = item.EventName;
                        return event;
                    }),
```

I managed to determine that neither item.StartDate nor its formatyee works, and the latter alerts 'Invalid date'. Following some further investigation after an unsuccessful attempt to format the date to 'YYYY-MM-DD', I managed to find [this solution](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2042#makechanges) which apparently is the same as mine, and OP manages to fix their problem.

**I can't seem to figure out how they managed to change the format to ISO8601.**

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here. Are you asking how to format dates in the Web Api call to ISO8601? Or how to parse the value when it gets to JavaScript?

Comment: I can't figure out how they format the date to iso8601. I manage to parse it but it's in the wrong format so the Events don't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was converting the Date, before it even gets to the Javascript (when I was getting it from the Database) to a wrong format that even the JS had hard time fixing. For anyone else having problems with the Events on different browsers, just convert your start/end dates to be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" or "yyyy-MM-dd" if you're not using the time variable and it should all be just fine.